# Optashift versus Optaplanner differences?

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I want to use Optashift/Optaplanner for myself.
I see they're similar, but different. Correct me if I'm wrong:

- The solution search algorithm is the same in both on them.
- However, Optaplanner is Java GUI based and Optashift is web based.
- Optashift requires an Openshift instance to run. (point for Optaplanner)
- Optaplanner uses Drool (I haven't found any .drl file in Optashift though)(point for Optashift)
- Watching the demo, Optashift looks as if it's more 'developed'. You could make changes on the provided solution while in the Optaplanner program you could only switch workers in a turn.(point for optashift)

So far I have to make a solution with a special working shift (6 working days, 2 rest days, 6 work, 2 rest, 6 work and 3 rest). 
I also have to take into consideration what have they done the 27 days before to 'continue' the 6,2,6,2,6,3 pattern, but I don't know how to do this. I thought I should assign a variable to each worker so that is specifies which day of the 27 cycle should start with. For example, iDayOfShift = 0 the worker starts fresh on the first day of the 27 cycle, but if iDayOfShift = 8 it means he is starting the second 6 working day cycle.

Would that be the correct approach to the solution?
I think Optashift is more complete than Optaplanner, do you see any reason/recommendation I shouldn't choose Optashift?